# Permanently create DOM element with VanillaJS class obj? (.insertAdjacentElement)

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created a new H4 element that renders in the DOM as intended. The problem is though, the element is not permanently rendering.

Clicking another image (Only 2 image tags) suddenly then adds the H4 element to the next image but removes the other. I looked around and couldn't find a related topic.

I appreciate your help.

```
class Player {
    constructor() {

        // Add elements and content for clicks.
        this.addHeader = document.createElement("h4");
        this.text = document.createTextNode('The number of times you have clicked:')
        this.addHeader.appendChild(this.text);
        console.log(this.addHeader);

        // Obtain images from HTML.
        this.images = document.querySelectorAll('.cat-image');
    }

    // Update when the image is clicked.
    update() {

        for (const image of this.images) {

            let compareSrc = image.attributes.getNamedItem('src'),
                ifcontainsH4 = Array.from(image.parentElement.childNodes).includes('h4');

            image.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

                (compareSrc === compareSrc) && !ifcontainsH4
                    ? image.parentElement.insertBefore(this.addHeader, image.parentElement.children[1])
                    : console.log('Parent element contains a h4 tag.');

                e.preventDefault();
            })
        }

    }
}

// Instance of class Player.
const player = new Player();

// Loop for event listeners that are apart of a class.
(function loop() {
    player.update();
})(this)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so your problem is reproducible and more readily answered.

Comment: Are you sure `Array.from(image.parentElement.childNodes).includes('h4')` works? It seems to be comparing DOM nodes to a string, which I would expect to always fail as *includes* uses `===`. Even comparing the tagname, it would most likely fail as most implementations will return 'H4'. Consider `image.parentNode.querySelector('h4')`, which should be much more efficient. :-)

Comment: @RobG This was my very first time attempting this. Yes it does work, however I really appreciate the your consideration. Your explanation of the DOM comparison helped me view that manner of code in better light.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for the tip, I will make sure to take care for my posts as such!

Comment: @BaoPham—I don't know what your criteria for "works" are, but you really should test them because `Array.from(image.parentElement.childNodes).includes('h4')` always returns *false*.

Comment: @Robg Apologizes. Yes, I tested and that method currently returns the correct output I am expecting and needed for my code. I expect for Array.from(image.parentElement.childNodes).includes('h4') === false upon clicking image. The comparison works as the H4 is added. I also usually try to console.log(before testing code in client) to make sure. I believe that is a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.addHeader runs when Player is constructed, and every click refers to it. Therefore it's just moving the same h4 element to each clicked image.

If you want a new h4 added on each click, then each click handler should create it's own h4 element.

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for. I appreciate the help.